# NodeJS(SocketIO)でdisconnectイベントを瞬時に取得したい

Tags: ios, node.js, websocket, socket.io

iphoneアプリとNodeJSでチャットのアプリケーションを作成している者です。

アプリからソケット接続を切断したら、サーバ側でdisconnectを検知するのに約30秒かかることが分かりました。

サーバサイドでdisconnectイベントをすぐに検知できずに困っています。

皆様のお知恵を拝借願えませんでしょうか?

どうぞよろしくお願いいたします。

<環境> 
   (サーバサイド) 
   ・NodeJS(v0.10.26) 
         - socket.io@1.3.6

(クライアントサイド) 
   ・swift1.6 
        - SIOSocket 
   ・Xcode6.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

以下のようなコードで**pintTimeout**と**pingInterval**を短くしたらダメでしょうか？

```
require('socket.io').listen(app, { pingTimeout: 4000, pingInterval: 4000 });
```

以下の英語版の回答を参考にしています。
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25402512/socket-io-random-disconnects-v1-0-6

Comment: tomuteさん、ありがとうございます。

Comment: @tokyo_kabutomushi  お役に立てて良かったです。